# Get attribute of children of a specify Parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a xml file that stored all config about flash-shockwave type in html **Embed** tag. 
i write this code to access from the xml file and join them into a string.
my following code is:
[image]

but this , i do'nt know why the flashSettingStr is Empty?

and my Following xml document is the:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should write

```
$(xml).children('Option').each(...
```

since `FlashSetting` isn't a children of itself (it is the root element)

Comment: It should also be noted that I'm using tag **Option** face some limitations.it mean's to the  **Option** tag is the child of another tag with that the name is **DisplaySetting** and so that i have access to the FlashSetting >>  Option

Comment: then use `find()` instead of `children()`

Comment: is your means this code?  $(xml).find("FlashSetting").find("Option").each(function(){//do Somethings})

Comment: I mean `$(xml).find('Option')`

Comment: I said in the first comment I have to Parent Tag with the name **FlashSetting** and **DisplaySetting**.your code find all **Option** Element that may be Exist in the **DisplaySetting** Tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $xml = $('<FlashSetting><Option name="a" value="b" /><Option name="c" value="d" />​​​​​​​​​</FlashSetting>')​​​​​​​​​​;
var flashSettingStr = [];
$xml.find("Option").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log($this);
    flashSettingStr.push($this.attr("name") + "=" + $this.attr("value"));
});
flashSettingStr = flashSettingStr.join(',');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu3J4/)**.